# Neo4j with Windows Powershell : xxxx is not a Neo4j Home directory

Tags: powershell, neo4j

I've installed Neo4j (exe installer) and I've also extracted the powershell module from the zip file but now when I try to do anything I just get an error message like:

```
PS C:\dev\github\neo4j-sandbox\src\ps> Get-Neo4jServer c:\dev\github\neo4j-sandbox\neo4jdb
Get-Neo4jServer : c:\dev\github\neo4j-sandbox\neo4jdb is not a Neo4j Home directory
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Neo4jServer c:\dev\github\neo4j-sandbox\neo4jdb
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Get-Neo4jServer
```

At first I thought perhaps I was misinterpreting what the neo4j "home directory" was and tried pointing it to the installation directory, but I just get the same error message.

```
PS C:\dev\github\neo4j-sandbox\src\ps> Get-Neo4jServer "c:\Program Files\Neo4j CE 2.3.2"
Get-Neo4jServer : c:\Program Files\Neo4j CE 2.3.2 is not a Neo4j Home directory
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Neo4jServer "c:\Program Files\Neo4j CE 2.3.2"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Get-Neo4jServer
```

So, what is the "Neo4j Home Directory" - I couldn't find a definition for that anywhere. Is it the data directory, or the installation directory, or something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that somehow or another the installation via the exe download is different from the installation in the zip. I would have expected them to be the same, with the exe version just being automated.

Anyway, if you extract the zip file and copy the contents of the `neo4j-community-2.3.2` (or appropriate for your version/edition) folder inside the zip file into a folder on your hard-drive, then point the PowerShell script at that folder it is happy to report the version of the installation.